# Как создать кликабельную сетку треугольников с использованием HTML, SVG?

Tags: css, svg, css-animation

Я уже создал сетку из треугольников, вот так:

```css
 svg {
      margin-left: 0px;
      margin-right: -60px;
      padding: 0;
    }
```

```html
<div data-bind="foreach: Grid">
  <div data-bind="foreach: $data.rowData">
    <!-- ko if: $data.owner() === 0 && ($data.pos[0] + $data.pos[1])%2 === 0-->
    <svg height="103.92" width="120">
      <polygon class="" points="60,0 0,103.92 120,103.92" style="fill:grey;" data-bind="click: $root.test.bind($data, $data)" />
    </svg>
    <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- ko if: $data.owner() === 0 && ($data.pos[0] + $data.pos[1])%2 === 1-->
    <svg height="103.92" width="120">
      <polygon class="" points="0,0 120,0 60,103.92" style="fill:grey;" data-bind="click: $root.test.bind($data, $data)" />
    </svg>
    <!-- /ko -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Моя проблема заключается в том, что только левая половина треугольников кликабельна.
 Я думаю, что это связано с (прямоугольной) формой  SVG-элемента. Но я понятия не имею как это исправить.
Есть ли способ сделать каждый треугольник кликабельным по всей его площади?

Источник: [How to create a clickable grid of triangles using html, svg?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34001691/how-to-create-a-clickable-grid-of-triangles-using-html-svg/34002110#34002110)

Comment: ассоциация:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34001691/how-to-create-a-clickable-grid-of-triangles-using-html-svg/34002110#34002110

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На данный момент, все Ваши индивидуальные фигуры SVG's накладываются одна на другую и любой клик, что не попадает в треугольник будет поглощен элементом родительского `<SVG>`.

Наилучшим решением было бы поместить все  полигоны в один большой SVG. Однако, есть еще один способ обойти вашу проблему, используя `pointer-events` свойство.

Установите `pointer-events:none;` для `<SVG>` элементов, так что клики будет проходить через них. Но вам также понадобится установить явный указатель-события -`pointer-events: fill;` на ваши полигоны, так как в противном случае они будут наследовать "нет" от своих родителей SVG's.

```js
 var output = document.getElementById("output");
    
document.getElementById("red").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  output.textContent = "red";
});

document.getElementById("green").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  output.textContent = "green";
});
```

```css
svg {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
}

polygon {
    pointer-events: fill;
}

#output {
  margin-top: 120px;
}
```

```html
<svg width="100px" height="100px">
    <polygon points="0,0,100,0,100,100" fill="red" id="red"/>
</svg>

<svg width="100px" height="100px">
    <polygon points="0,0,100,100,0,100" fill="green" id="green"/>
</svg>

<div id="output"></div>
```

Ответ: [Paul LeBeau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1292848/paul-lebeau)